# FFMPEG how to add image and soundwaves to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

I have an mp3 song that I am making a video for, I also have a background image.

My command that doesn't work.

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -i image.jpg -filter_complex \  "[0:a]showwaves=s=3840x200:mode=line[sw];" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a video.mp4
```

I'm trying to read the documentation and understand how to just put the image as a background, overlay the Soundwaves on the Image and keep the audio. Can someone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: Added bonus would be showwaves customization with color and histogram

Comment: Could you please try this: ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i song.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest video.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter to put the [showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves) on top of `image.jpg`:

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=3840x200:mode=line:colors=red|yellow[sw];[1][sw]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart video.mp4
```

- Adjust showwaves colors with the `colors` option. Each channel will have its own color, so in this example, if `song.mp3` is stereo, the left channel is red and the right channel is yellow.
- If you just want a single waveform of all channels add the [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) filter before showwaves, as in `aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=3840x200:mode=line:colors=00ff00`.